# Does anyone know how to calculate the inverse matrix of $I+\mu\mu^{\top}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

As stated above, I am stuck in calculating the inverse matrix of $I+\mu\mu^{\top}$, where $\mu$ is a unit vector, i.e. $\vert\mu\vert=1$ and $\vert\cdot\vert$ is $L^{2}$-norm.

Comment: You are aware of the fact that, for $A= I + cc^T$, $Av=v$ for every vector $v$ orthogonal to $c$, and $Ac = 2c$?

Comment: @Thomas only for a unit vector.

Comment: @IgorRivin if $v$ is orthogonal to $c$ then $Av = Iv =v$. $c$ has length $1$ by assumption (see the question. I did not repeat the assumption. If that's what you are complaining about you are right).

Comment: Try $I + \lambda \mu \mu^T$ with a suitable choice of $\lambda$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the [Sherman-Morrison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) formula
$$\eqalign{
(I+\mu\mu^\top)^{-1}
 &= I^{-1} - \frac{I^{-1}\mu\mu^\top I^{-1}}{1+\mu^\top I^{-1}\mu}  \cr
 &= I - \frac{\mu\mu^\top}{1+\mu^\top\mu} \cr
 &= I - \frac{1}{2}\mu\mu^\top  \cr
}$$

Comment: That is pretty cool! Thanks for such a huge help!

Answer (score 0):

Let $u\in L(\mathbb{R}^n)$ representing $A$ in the canonique base, thats means $u:x\to x+(\mu,x)\mu$ where $(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the inner product. Indeed $$AX=X+\mu\mu^TX=X+(\mu^TX)\mu$$

Analysis : Let $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, we want to solve $y=x+(\mu,x)\mu$.

Take the inner product with $\mu$ : $(\mu,y)=(\mu,x)(1+|\mu|^2)=2(\mu,x)$.

Then $x=y-(\mu,x)\mu=y-\frac{1}{2}(\mu,y)\mu$.

Synthesis : $A^{-1}=I-\frac{1}{2}\mu\mu^T$.

Comment: That is very helpful! I have one more question: for $<\mu,I>$, does the inner product give us a $\mu$ or $\mu^{\top}$?

Comment: If you take columns : $<X,Y>=X^TY$.

Comment: Thx! That is quite clear!